# KVO on UIImageView.transform is jumpy

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, key-value-observing

I am creating a custom wheel control for iOS using Swift. The wheel control will allow the user to drag to pick a value. The wheel control contains 12 labels but the user should be able to pick any value from 0 to 200 using this wheel. In order to achieve this effect, each label must be updated with an incremented value when it reaches a certain point.

[image]

I have registered the value observer like this:

```
imageBlueDialer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "transform", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

and written the code to update the label in:

```
observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!, ofObject object: AnyObject!, change: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, context: UnsafePointer<()>) { }
```

The labels get updated if the scrolling is slow but if I do a fast big swipe, the observer skips changes resulting in this:

[image]

**CAN ANYONE PLEASE GUIDE ME HOW TO MAKE MY VALUE OBSERVER MORE SENSITIVE? THANKS IN ADVANCE!**

Answer (score 4):

Don't watch the transform. Watch the data.

You're treating the transform as the actual value. Instead, your dialer should maintain an angle property based on the gesture recognizer. The transform and the dial's value should both be based on that property.

A good starting point is [RW-KnobControl](https://github.com/sammyd/RW-KnobControl). It's pretty easy to convert that code into Swift as well (I've done it once myself; just haven't gotten around to pushing it up to github).

Comment: Ok, let me try to fix it with the help of that knob control. Thanks man :)